# return XML data forcefully on .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core

I thought this would be simple but I'm running into an issue of forcefully returning XML data.

- system returns json by default
- controller that interfaces with SSRS requires xml output
- SSRS cannot send accept header to request xml data (that I can find)
- controller returns IActionResult

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that can request the GET URL and the XML formats the report controller only

I was hoping I would be able to send a configuration change before outputting data normally with `return Ok(obj);` but have not been able to find anything.

I've tried using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.Extensions nuget package but it seems like an overly complicated solution for what I'm looking for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you would like to restrict the response formats for a specific action you can, you can apply the `[Produces]` filter.

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public class YoursController
```

The `[Produces]` filter will force all actions within the `YoursController` to return XML-formatted responses, even if other formatters were configured for the application.

For more information refer [Forcing a Particular Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting) section.

Comment: Thank you, had a hard time finding something like this. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the JSON formatter from the list of formatters as below

```
// Remove the JSON formatter
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#removing-the-json-or-xml-formatter

Answer (score 0):

With .Net 6.0, I simply update the response's contentType property before returning my result object and the ASP Net Core handle the serialization :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

If the contentType property is null, the serialization defaults to json